# Can a knight jump into a square in both an odd and even number of moves?

Tags: knights

For example, a knight can go from b1 to d5 in 2 moves and in many other routes by an even number of moves. However, can it go to d5 in an odd number of moves?

I was wondering this because it would give me a little bit of insight into some theory.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No. There's a fairly simple proof by looking at the square colors: they alternate each move. That means the parity of the move count to travel between two squares is fixed.

Comment: Oh haha, I should have thought about that. Well, thank you for clearing.

Comment: This is actually relevant to actual play, e.g. from http://www.janko.at/Retros/d.php?ff=8/8/8/8/8/8/p1pK1n2/k7 White draws with Kc1! (but not Kc2? Nd3 0-1).